# How to create a new column using information from another column in pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
weather_train=pd.DataFrame({
'site_id':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
'air_temperature':[25,22,21,28,29,30,45,48,50,22,24]
 }
)
```

I would like add a new column called "Seasons" after the air_temperature column. The conditions are, if the air_temperature is less than or equal to 25, then it should output "winter" in Seasons column, if the air_temperature is in between 25 and 45 then it should output "summer" in the seasons column, if the air_temperature is greater than or equal to 45 then it should output "summer" in seasons column

**Picture**

[image: Picture]

I found that doing this in R is quite easy. But how can I do this in Pandas?

Comment: You want  `summer` twice?

Comment: Kindly post ur expected output

Comment: Sorry, when the air_temperature is in between 25 and 45 it should be "spring"

Comment: I already figured that, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert your continuous data to categorical. We use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for this:

```
weather_train['Seasons'] = pd.cut(weather_train['air_temperature'], 
                                  bins=[-float('inf'), 25, 45, float('inf')], 
                                  labels=['winter', 'spring', 'summer'])

    site_id  air_temperature Seasons
0         0               25  winter
1         0               22  winter
2         0               21  winter
3         0               28  spring
4         0               29  spring
5         0               30  spring
6         1               45  spring
7         1               48  summer
8         1               50  summer
9         1               22  winter
10        1               24  winter
```